# Why doesn't IIFE capture variables in its scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, closures, variable-assignment, iife

I'm doing some experimenting with closures in Javascript, and with AngularJS  directives (1.x) in particular.

To put it simply, I am wondering why **ScenarioOne** correctly captures the variable `message` that we want, while **ScenarioTwo** does not. Why does the IIFE not **capture and maintain** the desired value of `message` when it invokes itself?

**SCENARIO ONE**

```
 // WORKS. Displays 'We want this message'

  var message = 'We want this message';

  element.bind('click', (function(){
    var msg = message;   // <-- MAGIC ?
    return function(){
      element.append('<p>Value of message: ' + msg + '</p>');
    };
  })());

  message = 'We DON\'T want this message';
```

**SCENARIO TWO**

```
 // DOES NOT WORK. Displays 'We  DON'T want this message'
  var message = 'We want this message';

  element.bind('click', (function(){
    return function(){
      element.append('<p>Value of message: ' + message + '</p>');
    };
  })());

  message = 'We DON\'T want this message';
```

I would like to understand, what are the magic mechanics (see line denoted ***<-- MAGIC*** ) of that assignment? What is the general rule about this? Do all variables that you want from an outer scope need to explicitly assigned to a new variable inside the IIFE?

Here is a working Plunkr of all this: https://plnkr.co/edit/1M9yrzuOi0bzNHxbb5rO

Comment: `msg` isn't changed before the function is called. That's why it works. I'm not sure of what's unclear to you. Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript?rq=1 ?

Comment: See the linked question's answers. There's no magic involved. :-) In your second example, by the time your callback runs, you've changed the value of the `message` variable, so naturally you see the updated value when it's used in the `append` call. A closure closes over **the variable** ¹, not the variable's *contents* as of when the closure was created. *(¹ More accurately, it closes over the lexical environment object that contains the variable, but that's a detail...)*

Comment: Ok thanks I will read through the answers at the linked question. I guess I understood it wrong. I thought the IIFE creates it's own new version of the variables, beginning with their last value from the outer scope

Comment: The IIFE only provides a scope, and creates the variable `msg` in that. It doesn't really close over anything. The function that you return from the IIFE and bind to the event is the actual closure - and in one case it closes over `msg`, in the other case if closes over `message`.